# i have a question asks "Count the total number of orders with refunded order status."

Tags: sql, oracle

is there a command in oracle that can count the number of order with refunded status from a table named orders ? like in java i will just use a loop with count++; but idk what to do here

Answer (score 1):

As you do not provide table structure and sample data then it could be something like

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)CNTT FROM ORDERS WHERE STATUS='REFUNDED'
```

Comment: What is CNTT here?

Comment: alias for count(*)

Comment: it shows a column with CCNT name on it with 23 as a value, that means i have 23 number of refunded items right? and thanks dude, idk why the dr didnt showed us